# Localhost webservice connection from android device

Tags: c#, android, web-services, iis, localhost

I'm developing an android app and writing web services for that app on C#. So I need to try my webservices in my app from android device. I guess, for try my webservices from device, need to put my local IP address to instead of "localhost". And for use my local IP, i need to install IIS. I install IIS and put my IP to instead of localhost. I set binding settings from IIS manager.

IP:192.168.XX.XX
PORT:49244

I can access 192.168.XX.XX/49244 address, but when I try to access my webservices,192.168.1.36:49244/Service1.asmx, I get HTTP not found - detailed error.

What I need to do for access my services, where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you use an htaccess file on the server?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea about what is the htaccess file :(

Comment: Okay then I guess you don't have one :) Had a similar issue some time ago and htaccess was the problem.